# How can I get the current page from within the $().DataTable() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC web application and I am using DataTables.Net datatable v1.10.19 for my lists.

I am creating master/detail drill downs where the first list (DataTable) of job activity provides a link on each row to the respective detail record. I am using pagination as well.

On the detail record, I want to have a breadcrumb that takes me back to the job activity list, and to the correct page number where I was at then I clicked on the detail link.

What I am doing is passing the query properties I am using on the Job Activity DataTable as query string parameters to the detail page so I can correctly populate the breadcrumb URL back to the job activity page.

I can see on the [DataTable.Net API reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()) that I can use page.info() from the API to get the current page using something like this;

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var info = table.page.info();

$('#tableInfo').html(
    'Currently showing page '+(info.page+1)+' of '+info.pages+' pages.'
);
```

The problem is that I initialize the DataTable as part of the table setup and in the body of that function is where I am populating the link data for the detail page. I can't seem  to do two .DataTable() calls, such as doing the call to the DataTable function to get the page info to initialize a pageNumber variable and then call the main .DataTable function as it causes the init of the main DataTable function to fail.

So, I need a way to get the current page from within the main .Datatable() function, if possible.

Here is my main DataTable() function;

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        //Get the Timezone offset between local time and UTC
        var d = new Date();
        var m = d.getTimezoneOffset();
        var minutesToOffset = parseInt(m, 10);
        var companyId = $('#company-filter').val();
        var siteId = $('#site-filter').val();
        var aging = $('#aging-filter').val();

        console.log(`companyId: [${companyId}], siteId: [${siteId}], Aging Days: [${aging}]`);

        var table = $("#ssflist").DataTable({
            //"dom": "lrtip",
            "initComplete": function() {
                $('#spinner1').hide();
                $('#spinner2').hide();
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "order": [[6, "desc"]],
            "ajax": {
                "url": `/JobActivity/LoadData?companyId=${companyId}&siteId=${siteId}&agingDays=${aging}`,
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Filter"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": [9, 10] },
                { "className": "text-center", "targets": [0, 9, 10] },
                {
                    "targets": [6, 7],
                    "render": function(data) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            return moment(data).subtract(minutesToOffset, 'minutes').format('M/D/YYYY h:mm a');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (full.ManifestStatus === 0) {
                            return '<i class="far fa-clock text-primary" title="Not started"></i>';
                        } else if (full.ManifestStatus === 1) {
                            return '<i class="fas fa-sync-alt text-primary" title="Pending"></i>';
                        } else if (full.ManifestStatus === 2) {
                            return '<i class="far fa-file-alt text-primary" title="Manifested"></i>';
                        } else if (full.ManifestStatus === 3) {
                            return '<i class="far fa-times-circle text-danger" title="Failed"></i>';
                        } else if (full.ManifestStatus === 4) {
                            return '<i class="far fa-check-circle text-primary" title="Uploaded"></i>';
                        } else return '<i class="far fa-question-circle text-primary" title="Unknown status"></i>';
                    },
                    "name": "ManifestStatus"
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (type === 'display' && data != null) {
                            data =
                                `<a href="/shippingServicesFileDetail/detail?id=${full.Id
                                }&returnTitle=Job Activity List&companyId=${companyId}&siteId=${siteId}&agingDays=${
                                aging}">
                                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">` +
                                data +
                                `</button></a>`;
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    "data": "Id",
                    "name": "Id"
                },
                { "data": "TransactionId", "name": "TransactionId", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CompanyName", "name": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "SiteName", "name": "SiteName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "ReferenceId", "name": "ReferenceId", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CreatedDate", "name": "CreatedDate", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "UploadDate", "name": "UploadDate", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "Environment", "name": "Environment", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {

                        data = full.H1RecordCount + full.D1RecordCount + full.C1RecordCount;
                        return data;
                    },
                    "name": "Count"
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (full.AzureFileUrl != null) {
                            data =
                                `<a href="/JobActivity/getManifest?azureFileUrl=${full.AzureFileUrl
                                }&azureFileName=${full.AzureFileName}">
                                                        <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down text-primary" title="Download Manifest"></a>`;
                            return data;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "AzureFileUrl"
                }
            ],
            // From StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/33377633/1988326 - hides pagination if only 1 page
            "preDrawCallback":
                function(settings) {
                    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
                    var pagination = $(this)
                        .closest('.dataTables_wrapper')
                        .find('.dataTables_paginate');
                    pagination.toggle(api.page.info().pages > 1);
                },
        });

        $('#companyId').on('change',
            function() {
                table.search(this.text).draw();
            });
    });
```

The relevant link code is...

```
data = `<a href="/shippingServicesFileDetail/detail?id=${full.Id                                   
}&returnTitle=Job Activity 
List&companyId=${companyId}&siteId=${siteId}&agingDays=${
aging}">
```

I want to add a parameter to this link that represents the current page of the Datatable so that I can pass it back in the breadcrumb link on the detail page and have the datatable go to the correct page.

So I need a way to get the current page from within the

```
var table = $("#ssflist").DataTable({
```

function itself so I can pass that value in the link to the detail page.

Is there a property or method from within the Datatable function that will get me the current page value?

Comment: My English and my Javascript skills are too weak to follow your post, but can't you use the [infoCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback) ?

Comment: What I ended up doing was enabling state with sessions on the DataTable. This allowed me to not only return to the page but also retain the filter.  I used                 "stateSave": true,  "stateDuration": -1,  and then table.state.clear if I needed to reset the state programmatically.